# Customer ordering of posts using ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I've added a custom field to my CPT called `order` where the user can assign a numerical value to a post.

This works, however I've advised the client to use increments of 10 (in case they ever need to add posts at a later date).

The issue is that it's currently ordering like this

```
0 
10
100
110
120
130
140
150
160
170
180
190
20
200
210
220
```

and so forth. I need them to sort by the following

```
0 
10
20
30
```

These are the args I'm using in the loop

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => array( 'team' ),
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'order',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'ASC'
);
```

Any idea on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use `meta_value_num` instead of `meta_value`.

Leaving this here in case anyone encounters the same thing.